# How to display error messages during .configure to the standard console?

Tags: command-line, compiling, output, configure, stdout

When compiling from source, we use `.configure` as the first step. `.configure` may call some other commands like `cc` which may fail and print error messages, like header not found or some other compile errors. But these error messages are not displayed on the standard console where I run `.configure`. This causes difficulty in troubleshooting because sometimes `.configure` will only tell you it fails. So, how to force error messages of commands called during `.configure` to be displayed on the standard console, possibly multiplexed with other normal `.configure` messages?

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify which package you are dealing with.

Regardless, the output (stdout, stderr, and other info) of `./configure` (not `.configure`) is not lost.
It is typically contained in files in the working directory, e.g., `config.log`.